# Why this code snippet works with C++17 whereas the compiler complains when using C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17

Why this code snippet works with C++17 whereas the compiler complains when using C++11(i.e https://godbolt.org/z/71G91P)?
Are there any potential problems with this code snippet?

```
#include<iostream>

class ctx
{
    public:
        int map_create(void*){std::cout << "haha" << std::endl; return 0;};
};

ctx obj;
typedef int (ctx::*ctx_mem_func)(void*);

template <ctx_mem_func func>
int regHelper(void*) 
{
    ((&obj)->*func)(nullptr);
    return 0;
}

constexpr ctx_mem_func testFunc = &ctx::map_create;

typedef int(*callBackFunc)(void*);

int reg(callBackFunc)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    reg(regHelper<testFunc>);
    //But this expression is ok.
    reg(regHelper<&ctx::map_create>);
    
    std::cout << "this is a test" << std::endl;
}
```

Here are the error messages when using c++11(gun 10.0.2):

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:30:28: error: no matches converting function 'regHelper' to type 'callBackFunc {aka int (*)(void*)}'
     reg(regHelper<testFunc>);
                            ^
<source>:13:5: note: candidate is: template<int (ctx::* func)(void*)> int regHelper(void*)
 int regHelper(void*) 
     ^
```

Comment: "the compiler complains".... what compiler? in what mode? where? [edit] to quote all errors in full!

Comment: I get an error also with c++17 (https://godbolt.org/z/vKn87Y). What compiler are you using? What error do you get?

Comment: Unless C++17 relaxed the requirement for `constexpr` template parameters to plain `const` expressions in some circumstances, this ain't going to fly.

Comment: When asking about build errors, always include the full and complete error output in the question, copy-pasted as text. Also add comments in the code on the lines where you get the errors. And also tell us how you build the program, all options and flags provided. And please make questions *self-contained* with all relevant information inside the question itself.

Comment: Here is the test: https://godbolt.org/z/71G91P. The complier complains.

Comment: your test isnt the same code as the one you posted here. Please include a [mcve] of your code together with the error message in the question

Comment: cannot reproduce the error with the code in your question: https://godbolt.org/z/7hc3dT. Why don't you post the same code in the quesiton as you have in the godbolt link?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Try this https://godbolt.org/z/71G91P. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: I saw it, I think all is missing from the quesiton is the first couple of lines. Please do post a [mcve]. Details do matter. I know that the code in the question is not the same as the one in the godbolt link, but to be sure that it is only the first couple of lines missing I would have to compare them line by line to see if there is any other difference.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I see. I have edited it. I shall be more carefull later.

Comment: yes, now it isnt as confusing anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a difference between C++14 and C++17. [Simplified](https://godbolt.org/z/M6rh1M):

```
int f();
template<int (&)()> struct S {};
constexpr auto& q = f;
using R = S<q>; // valid in C++17, invalid in C++14
```

The change is to [Allow constant evaluation for all non-type template arguments](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4268.html), meaning that now a `constexpr` variable naming a function (member function, etc.) is permissible as an NTTP where previously only the actual name of the function was permitted.